# Possible to perform vertex blending (skinning) on OpenGl ES 1.1 ipod Touch?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm currently trying to make a simple model viewer for the iPod Touch, and I managed to render the model meshes where vertex blending is not performed (that is, mesh is attached to a single skeleton bone matrix).

In cases were a mesh use weights to perform blending, is there a way to do it in the ipod Touch using OpenGL ES 1.1?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the implementation you’re running on supports [`OES_matrix_palette`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_matrix_palette.txt) (which should be the case on every iPhone and iPod touch so far), you can transform each vertex by a weighted mix of a few matrices from a palette. The maximum number of matrices per vertex and palette size are implementation-dependent, but the spec mandates at least 3 matrices from a palette of at least 9.

On newer devices, matrix palette transformation is always performed on the GPU. On older hardware, you may wind up with a software fallback if you enable more than 2 fixed-function lights. You may still want to consider using your own software vertex transformation if vertex size becomes a bottleneck on older devices.

Comment: thanks for the information.now I know i have a alternative method, depending on my application constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There's no hardware support for vertex blending but you can always do the blending yourself on the CPU. Here's a [link](http://code.google.com/p/vfpmathlibrary/) to a VFP optimized math library.